# Convert String minutes seconds to Int

Tags: ios, swift, string, int

I've a string with minutes and seconds in format "minutes:seconds". For example, "5:36". I want to convert it to Int value. For example "5:36" string should be 336 Int value. How this can be done?

Comment: `Int(m) * 60 + Int(s)`

Comment: Next time, try to solve it yourself first and post your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple extension you can use which will validate the format of your input string too:

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    func toSeconds() -> Int? {

        let elements = components(separatedBy: ":")

        guard elements.count == 2 else {
            print("Provided string doesn't have two sides separated by a ':'")
            return nil
        }

        guard let minutes = Int(elements[0]),
        let seconds = Int(elements[1]) else {
           print("Either the minute value or the seconds value cannot be converted to an Int")
            return nil
        }

        return (minutes*60) + seconds

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let testString1 = "5:36"
let testString2 = "35:36"

print(testString1.toSeconds()) // prints: "Optional(336)"
print(testString2.toSeconds()) // prints: "Optional(2136)"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let timeString = "5:36"
let timeStringArray = timeString.split(separator: ":")
let minutesInt = Int(timeStringArray[0]) ?? 0
let secondsInt = Int(timeStringArray[1]) ?? 0
let resultInt = minutesInt * 60 + secondsInt
print(resultInt)
```

Comment: It's wrong way , You should first convert into date format

Comment: No @PrashantTukadiya, it's the right way. OP didn't say the string is a clock time value, just that is it "minutes:seconds". It could be a timer with: "2000:30". In which case a conversion to DateFormat wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your example on the playground here's the code:

```
import Foundation

let time1String = "0:00"
let time2String = "5:36"

let timeformatter        = DateFormatter()
timeformatter.dateFormat = "m:ss"

let time1 = timeformatter.date(from: time1String)
let time2 = timeformatter.date(from: time2String)

if let time1 = time1 {
    print(time2?.timeIntervalSince(time1)) // prints: Optional(336.0)
}
```

Comment: This won't work with `let time2String = "99:36"` because it assumes the string is a clock time. But it doesn't have to be. What if it is a timer counting up the seconds and minutes? Also coverting from String to Date twice is inefficient and unnecessary if you simply split the String and convert to Ints.

Comment: This also won't work the String `"5:36"`, which was OPs original request. For this to work the format has to be `"05:36"`.

Comment: Edited to make it work for "5:36". "99:36" doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't it be "1:00:00" after "59:59"?

Comment: Sure, depends on the requirements